# autopostgresqlbackup postgres authentication error

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, postgresql, database-backup

I am trying to use autopostgresqlbackup on ubuntu on an ec2 instance. I can log in with psql on the command line and it is picking up my .pgpass file and everything looks fine. When I run 'sudo autopostgresqlbackup' it just hangs and my error file mentions it's waiting for a password for the postgres user.

Here's my config files and error log.  I am using the ubuntu user and my /home/ubuntu/.pgpass file is setup with 0600 permissions. I'm guessing this has something to do with what user I am logged in with and what user to specify in the SU_USERNAME config line.  Should I be setting SU_USERNAME=ubuntu?  Any help here would be appreciated.  Thanks.

/etc/default/autopostgresqlbackup

```
# ===============================
# === Debian specific options ===
#================================

# By default, on Debian systems, only 'postgres' user
# is allowed to access PostgreSQL databases without password.
# In order to dump databases we need to run pg_dump/psql
# commands as 'postgres' with su.
#
# The following setting has been added to workraound this issue.
# (if it is set to empty, 'su' usage will be disabled)
SU_USERNAME=postgres

#=====================================================================
# Set the following variables to your system needs
# (Detailed instructions below variables)
#=====================================================================

# Username to access the PostgreSQL server e.g. dbuser
USERNAME=postgres

# Password
# create a file $HOME/.pgpass containing a line like this
#   hostname:*:*:dbuser:dbpass
# replace hostname with the value of DBHOST and postgres with 
# the value of USERNAME

# Host name (or IP address) of PostgreSQL server e.g localhost
DBHOST=localhost

# List of DBNAMES for Daily/Weekly Backup e.g. "DB1 DB2 DB3"
DBNAMES="all"
```

/var/lib/autopostgresqlbackup/ERRORS_localhost-881271020.log

```
Password for user postgres: 
Session terminated, terminating shell... ...killed.
```

pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host        all         all      207.244.165.220/32        md5
host        all         all      207.244.173.30/32        md5
```

Comment: If your own user already has access to the database, why do you use sudo to run the script?

Comment: Since the script needs to create directories in /var/lib/ I was getting permission denied errors.

Comment: I just left the setting empty and it worked for me.